# How to add elements to an observable stream by Observable.Timer based on stream values?

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactive-programming

I hope the title is clear enough. I'm toying around with Rx ideas and came across a question I'm not sure how to sove.

I have an input of events in some original form, say `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3, 4 }` is transformed into an input of some new form, say `IType`. Let's say that whenever number `2` is observed, a timer starts ticking and inserts a new transformed value (or, say, number `6`) to the stream unless number `5` is encountered, in which case the timer is cancelled.

I'm thinking to build a state machine that takes input from various sources. It would be nice if I could have "timed" events as part of the stream too.

The code follows, but basically I'm currently stuck with some ideas of using [Observable.Generate](http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/04_CreatingObservableSequences.html) (i.e. to make it look like a `Observable.Timer`, but to return/insert a new event to the input sequence) and/or perhaps something like `Observable.TakeUntil`, `Observable.Create` and merging streams but I'm not sure if there are better ways and even how to pull this off in terms of code.

In terms of code it could be something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reactive.Linq;
using System.Reactive.Subjects;


namespace RxTesting
{

    public interface IType
    {
        int OriginalInput { get; set; }
    }


    public class SomeEvent: IType
    {
        public int OriginalInput { get; set; }
    }


    public class TimeEvent: IType
    {
        public int OriginalInput { get; set; }
    }

     class  Program
     {
         static  void  Main(string[] args)
         {
             //Here we should have one TimerEvent after the last "2" in the sequence.
             var input = new Subject<int>();
             input.Select(i => new SomeEvent { OriginalInput = i }).SomeTimerOperatorHere().Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);

             input.OnNext(1);
             input.OnNext(2);
             input.OnNext(3);
             input.OnNext(4);
             input.OnNext(5);
             input.OnNext(1);
             input.OnNext(2);
             input.OnNext(3);
             input.OnNext(4);

             input.Dispose();
             Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Here in the console there should be one `RxTesting.TimerEvent` printed, since there is one `2`, after which there isn't number `5` cancelling its effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it - I think you are on the right lines with your `TakeUntil` idea.

We are filtering the events to include only those with `OriginalInput` of 2 and projecting each one to a single valued delayed stream with value 6 that is cut off if an event with `OriginalInput` of 5 arrives. The resulting stream of streams is flattened with a `SelectMany`.

```
public static IObservable<IType> SomeTimerOperatorHere(
  this IObservable<SomeEvent> source)
{
  var delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

  return Observable.Create<IType>(o => {

    var sourcePub = source.Publish().RefCount();

    return sourcePub
      .Where(x => x.OriginalInput == 2)
      .SelectMany(type => 
        Observable.Return(new TimeEvent{ OriginalInput = 6 })
                  .Delay(delay)
                  .TakeUntil(sourcePub.Where(x => x.OriginalInput == 5))
      ).Subscribe(o);
  });
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay as I'm not on the computer yet (will be within the next 12 hours or so, but probably goes to tomorrow). That idea with ``Delay`` is a succinct one, for what I gather reading it (not testing as no compiler), but what would be an equally good way to combine the produced ``TimeEvents`` with the original stream? Hmm, maybe I've got the idea. Thanks!